# How to override/remove default handler in GWT widget?

Tags: java, gwt

I would like to change a behavior of SuggestBox in GWT. I want submit value by pressing ENTER. However the SuggestBox have a KeyHandler, which catches any enter key and sets a new Selection. I am looking for a solution to remove/overide this Handler.

This method is called by constructor in SuggestBox

```
private void addEventsToTextBox() {
class TextBoxEvents extends HandlesAllKeyEvents implements
    ValueChangeHandler<String> {

  public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
    switch (event.getNativeKeyCode()) {
      case KeyCodes.KEY_DOWN:
        display.moveSelectionDown();
        break;
      case KeyCodes.KEY_UP:
        display.moveSelectionUp();
        break;
      case KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER:
      case KeyCodes.KEY_TAB:
        Suggestion suggestion = display.getCurrentSelection();
        if (suggestion == null) {
          display.hideSuggestions();
        } else {
          setNewSelection(suggestion);
        }
        break;
    }
    delegateEvent(SuggestBox.this, event);
  }

  public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
    delegateEvent(SuggestBox.this, event);
  }

  public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
    // After every user key input, refresh the popup's suggestions.
    refreshSuggestions();
    delegateEvent(SuggestBox.this, event);
  }

  public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
    delegateEvent(SuggestBox.this, event);
  }
}

TextBoxEvents events = new TextBoxEvents();
events.addKeyHandlersTo(box);
box.addValueChangeHandler(events);
```

}

Is it possible to remove this Handler from box by using HandlerRegistration? Is there any nice solution by extending class and overriding private method?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as the method is private, unless you copy the source directly and change the method that way you won't be able to override the method. I think your best option is to create an instance of SuggestBox and passing it a custom implementation of TextBoxBase which you can then override event/handler behaviours. Notice that the addEventsToTextBox() hooks up that inner class to the `box` member variable that is set in the constructor prior to the call to `addEventsToTextBox()`.

Something similar to the following:

```
public class MyTextBox extends TextBox{
...
// Override the handlers/events
...
}
```

and then use it with your instance of a SuggestBox:

```
MyTextBox myBox = new MyTextBox(...);
SuggestBox sBox = new SuggestBox(oracle, myBox);
```

Depending on your specific situation this might not be an ideal solution in which case it would be helpful to see some code snippets showing your use of it.

**EDIT:**

I should mention that you probably actually want to extend a subclass of TextBoxBase such as `TextBox` or `TextArea` and not `TextBoxBase` directly so you don't have to re-implement the basic text input functionality of those widgets.